# Can I use ati opencl with hybrid video card (intel/ati)

Tags: python, linux, opencl, xorg

I'm trying to setup a system to learn opencl on my laptop running Arch Linux. Laptop has hybrid video card (intel HD4000 and ati 8790). I installed AMD-APP-SDK and I'm able to run the sample pyopencl code:

```
import pyopencl as cl
cl.get_platforms()[0].get_devices()
```

however this only shows the CPU device:

```
[<pyopencl.Device 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4800MQ CPU @ 2.70GHz' on 'AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing' at 0xf55130>]
```

the output of clinfo is:

```
Number of platforms:                 1
  Platform Profile:              FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:              OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (1642.5)
  Platform Name:                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor:               Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Extensions:               cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices 


  Platform Name:                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices:               1
  Device Type:                   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
  Vendor ID:                     1002h
  Board name:                    
  Max compute units:                 8
  Max work items dimensions:             3
    Max work items[0]:               1024
    Max work items[1]:               1024
    Max work items[2]:               1024
  Max work group size:               1024
  Preferred vector width char:           16
  Preferred vector width short:          8
  Preferred vector width int:            4
  Preferred vector width long:           2
  Preferred vector width float:          8
  Preferred vector width double:         4
  Native vector width char:          16
  Native vector width short:             8
  Native vector width int:           4
  Native vector width long:          2
  Native vector width float:             8
  Native vector width double:            4
  Max clock frequency:               606Mhz
  Address bits:                  64
  Max memory allocation:             2147483648
  Image support:                 Yes
  Max number of images read arguments:       128
  Max number of images write arguments:      64
  Max image 2D width:                8192
  Max image 2D height:               8192
  Max image 3D width:                2048
  Max image 3D height:               2048
  Max image 3D depth:                2048
  Max samplers within kernel:            16
  Max size of kernel argument:           4096
  Alignment (bits) of base address:      1024
  Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:    128
  Single precision floating point capability
    Denorms:                     Yes
    Quiet NaNs:                  Yes
    Round to nearest even:           Yes
    Round to zero:               Yes
    Round to +ve and infinity:           Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:         Yes
  Cache type:                    Read/Write
  Cache line size:               64
  Cache size:                    32768
  Global memory size:                8278106112
  Constant buffer size:              65536
  Max number of constant args:           8
  Local memory type:                 Global
  Local memory size:                 32768
  Max pipe arguments:                16
  Max pipe active reservations:          16
  Max pipe packet size:              2147483648
  Max global variable size:          1879048192
  Max global variable preferred total size:  1879048192
  Max read/write image args:             64
  Max on device events:              0
  Queue on device max size:          0
  Max on device queues:              0
  Queue on device preferred size:        0
  SVM capabilities:              
    Coarse grain buffer:             Yes
    Fine grain buffer:               Yes
    Fine grain system:               Yes
    Atomics:                     Yes
  Preferred platform atomic alignment:       0
  Preferred global atomic alignment:         0
  Preferred local atomic alignment:      0
  Kernel Preferred work group size multiple:     1
  Error correction support:          0
  Unified memory for Host and Device:        1
  Profiling timer resolution:            1
  Device endianess:              Little
  Available:                     Yes
  Compiler available:                Yes
  Execution capabilities:                
    Execute OpenCL kernels:          Yes
    Execute native function:             Yes
  Queue on Host properties:              
    Out-of-Order:                No
    Profiling :                  Yes
  Queue on Device properties:                
    Out-of-Order:                No
    Profiling :                  No
  Platform ID:                   0x7f22c575efd0
  Name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4800MQ CPU @ 2.70GHz
  Vendor:                    GenuineIntel
  Device OpenCL C version:           OpenCL C 1.2 
  Driver version:                1642.5 (sse2,avx)
  Profile:                   FULL_PROFILE
  Version:                   OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1642.5)
  Extensions:                    cl_khr_fp64 cl_amd_fp64 cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_ext_device_fission cl_amd_device_attribute_query cl_amd_vec3 cl_amd_printf cl_amd_media_ops cl_amd_media_ops2 cl_amd_popcnt cl_khr_spir cl_khr_gl_event
```

I'm currently using intel as my video driver. I often switch between different monitor setups and intel supports xrandr very well so I'd like to keep using it but enable ati driver just for opencl computation. Is this possible at all? If it is, what should I do to accomplish that?

Comment: added the output of clinfo to the post

Answer (score 1):

To leverage the Intel HD4000 you'll need the Intel OpenCL driver installed. Only the AMD platform is showing up in your clinfo dump.

Answer (score 0):

Since AMD APP SDK 2.6 you need Catalyst driver to develop & run OpenCL-enabled software.